# How to grab a post ID

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to build a Youtube video community voting site. Each video that is posted gets a LIKE and DISLIKE button - but I can't figure out how to grab which video is liked and tie that to the video's ID.
Here is my code that lists out the existing videos:

```
<div class="row">
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
extract($row);
echo "<div class='span4'>";
    echo "<p>Username: " . $username . "</p>";
     echo "<p>Title: " . $title . "</p>";
     echo "<p>Description: " . $description . "</p>";
     echo "<p>Likes: " . $thumbUp . "</p>";
     echo "<p>Dislikes: " . $thumbDown . "</p>";

     echo "<form action='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]' method='POST'>";
     echo "<input type='submit' name='like' value='Like' class='btn' />";
     echo "<input type='submit' name='dislike' value='Disike' class='btn' />";
     echo "</form>";
     echo "</div>";
     echo "<div class='span8'>";
?>
<iframe width='560' height='315' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo($url); ?>?rel=0' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>
<?php
    echo "</div>";
}
?>  
</div>
```

I'm trying to use
   if(isset($_POST[like])) but can't figure out how to grab the video ID.
Any ideas?

Comment: send it with a `input type="hidden"` field

Comment: Thanks! Is that the best approach? Or should I be doing this differently?

Comment: you can also append it to the form action and retrieve it as a `$_GET` variable, but in this case `$_POST` is better, so stick with it :)